# Select an image source in a list with a style in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in HTML :

```
<div id="thumbs_list">
    <ul id="thumbs_list_frame">
        <li id="thumbnail_260" style="display: none;">...</li>
        <li id="thumbnail_261" style="display: none;">...</li>
        <li id="thumbnail_262" style="display: none;">...</li>
        <li id="thumbnail_264" style="display: list-item;">
            <a href='mywebsite.com'>
                <img src="myphoto.png" alt="Photo"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="thumbnail_266" style="display: none;">...</li>          
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm looking to get the source of the image who is in `<li>` with `style="display: list-item;"` (`myphoto.png`) with jQuery but I don't know how to do...

I tried this :

```
var firstThumbnailDisplay = $('#thumbs_list_frame li').css('display') == 'list-item';
var img = firstThumbnailDisplay.find("img").first().attr('src');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: why dont you add a "selected" class to the li-element and select by $('.classname') to make it a bit less hacky

Comment: @Fuzzyma : get the image source of the listpoint who have style="display: list-item;"

Comment: All of the below are testing for visible, visible !== list-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var src = $("#thumbs_list_frame li").filter(":visible:first").find("img").attr("src");
```

It finds the first visible (style not set to `display: none;`) `li` and gets the `src` attribute of the image inside it.

Comment: There are a number of fatal flaws to this, firstly `:visible` does not check for `list-item` it checks if it's visible. This will also return when `display:block`. [Secondly if more than one is visible src == undefined](http://jsfiddle.net/KZ97m/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:visible` selector.

`var firstThumbnailDisplay = $('#thumbs_list_frame li:visible')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `:visible` to find the one that is displayed and after with `.find()` and `.attr()` to acheive your goal.

```
var src = $('.result').html($('#thumbs_list_frame li:visible').find('img').attr('src'));
```

[**Here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lub8P/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
//declare an array (there could be multiple)
var listItems = [];
//Loop the items
$('#thumbs_list_frame li').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   //check for value
   if ($this.css('display') === 'list-item') {
     //push item into array
     listItems.push($this);
   }
});

//listItems now contains all list items with display:list-item;
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwkL5/1/)